# Is it safe to delete system partition on disk that used to hold OS in multiple disk desktop PC?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I have a desktop Windows 10, 64 bit, and one of the disks I'm attaching via SATA is from an old laptop, that laptop used to have Windows 10 installed on it. So the system files are still on it.

I see there are 2 extra partitions when i go in device manager, (although I can't delete them...) but I would like to, I'll try with Ease Us or something?

But is it safe to do so? And if ok, what tool should I use to do this, the area is greyed out and can't be formated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to back up those partitions first using `clonezilla` or similar, they will contain the system restore disk images, etc. for whatever hardware they came from.

But yes, delete away.  Personally I like to know that disks aren't in use, etc. when playing with partitions, and so I boot a live DVD of Mint or Ubuntu and run `sudo gparted`

Comment: Neither of those partitions will contain any kind of restore files, and _there's absolutely no reason whatsoever to back them up_. The purpose of the 499MB partition is to store the WinRE image, whereas the purpose of the 100MB EFI partition is to house the boot files since the BIOS firmware is UEFI. There is also no reason to utilize any 3rd party software, as Windows supports removing the partitions natively via `DiskPart`.

Comment: They don't show up in Dispart form command prompt, used Ease Us and they are gone ;)

Comment: @BrunoVincent Please elaborate, as you're not issuing the correct commands then, since it's fundamentally impossible for Disk Management to show drives & partitions not present in `DiskPart` since Disk Management utilizes `DiskPart` on the backend. Your comment is also incredulous considering I provided the exact commands required in my answer... _You can see what should be shown via [my example on PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/7M4c7Q4j)._

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can delete those partitions and it won't affect anything on your current operating system.

If there is nothing on the entire disk that is needed, I like HDDGURU.

http://hddguru.com/software/HDD-LLF-Low-Level-Format-Tool/

It's a quick and simple program that does a low level format. After, just format it to NTFS in disk manager.

I've had some issues using Easy Us in the past, so I tend to stay away from their products. 
You can easily do this in CMD using diskpart

https://www.disk-partition.com/diskpart/delete-partition-4125.html

This link should give you a good idea of how to remove the partitions, but you will need to use  'delete partition override' to remote the system protected partitions.

Comment: Windows natively supports deleting, and/or formatting, the partitions via `diskpart`.    Once deleted via `diskpart`, `diskmgmt.msc` can be utilized to resize the next closest partition.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to do so.

### To Remove Partitions:

1. <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. `diskpart`

   1. `sel dis 2`
   2. `lis par`
   3. `sel par 2`

      - `det par`

        - *Should be 100MB EFI partition*
   4. `del par override`
   5. `sel par 1`

      - `det par`

        - *Should be 499MB System WinRE partition*
   6. `del par override`
   7. `exit`

### Microsoft Docs:

- [Hard Drives and Partitions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/hard-drives-and-partitions)

  - [UEFI/GPT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions)

    - [Partion Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-setup-diskconfiguration-disk-modifypartitions-modifypartition-typeid#uefigpt-based-systems)
  - [BIOS/MBR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-biosmbr-based-hard-drive-partitions)

    - [Partition Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-setup-diskconfiguration-disk-modifypartitions-modifypartition-typeid#biosmbr-based-systems)
- [DiskPart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart)

### Partitions:

- **499MB**

  - ***GPT Type:*** `de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac`
  - ***MBR Type:*** `0x27`
  - ***Purpose:*** WinRE partition
- **100MB**

  - ***Type:*** `c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b`
  - ***Purpose:*** EFI Boot Partition